# Can akka persistentview receive messages in reverse order of what is persisted?

Tags: akka, akka-persistence, journaling

In other words, can recent history of messages be quickly accessed from a journal?

Say, the persisted journal messages in order:

A, B, C, D and E consecutively.

Can a persistent-view receive the messages in order:
E, D, C, B and then A?

Comment: I don't think that's a pre-offered option, but you can write your own journal plugin and allow such a thing.

Comment: Thanks. I'll surely take a look at the code and try to suggest/make changes.

Comment: I didn't exactly mean that you should create a pull request to main codebase (which would still be nice) for a feature like this one, which I honestly don't see having many use cases. I meant that a journal is just an interface that you can implement to make it do w/ever you like it to :)